# approval on proof about ultra - metric

Tags: metric-spaces

I am trying to proove that if $(X,d)$ is a metric space with this propery:
 $$y\in B(x,r)\Rightarrow B(x,r) = B(y,r)$$
then the metric is an ultra metric.

**This is my proof**:

Let $x,y,z\in X$ be some arbitrary elements in the space. Let $r=\max\{d(x,y),d(y,z)\}$ and also let $\varepsilon >0$ be some positive number.
notice that $y\in B(x,r+\varepsilon)$ and also $z\in B(y,r+\varepsilon)$. By the given property we can conclude that $$B(x,r+\varepsilon)=B(y,r+\varepsilon)$$
Then $z\in B(x, r+\varepsilon )$, so:
$$d(x,z)<r+\varepsilon=max\{d(x,y),d(y,z)\}+\varepsilon$$

and this is true for all $\varepsilon >0$, so when $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ we get:
$$d(x,z)\leq max\{d(x,y),d(y,z)\}$$
So $d$ is an ultra metric.
$\blacksquare$

Is this a legal proof? Is the last transition correct? I am 99% precent sure but still I just want to get some clarification.

Comment: if you can't convince yourself how to convince other people  ?

Comment: @Thomas I am showing you a proof and you detmire if you think it is a good one or not

Answer (score 1):

Yep, looks good. The last transition is valid, and is a standard trick in analysis. If you want to prove it, then prove it indirectly. Suppose that
$$d(x, z) > \max\{d(x, y), d(y, z)\},$$
and consider the particular $\varepsilon$,
$$\varepsilon = d(x, z) - \max\{d(x, y), d(y, z)\} > 0.$$